# SVG sprite generator converting simple shapes to complex paths

Tags: svg

Do you know why my simple shapes are being converted to paths (which are more complex shapes)?

I have an example of my file versus what the SVG generator creates: [codepen](https://codepen.io/OGHP/pen/MvdObj?editors=1100)

My svg:

```
<svg id="cancel" viewBox="0 0 25 25" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.8px" stroke-linecap="round">
    <title>Cancel</title>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.53" r="12.08" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <line x1="17.86" y1="7.86" x2="7.86" y2="17.86" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <line x1="17.84" y1="17.84" x2="7.88" y2="7.88" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Generator svg:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25">
<title>cancel</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.8" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" d="M24.58 12.53c0 6.672-5.408 12.080-12.080 12.080s-12.080-5.408-12.080-12.080c0-6.672 5.408-12.080 12.080-12.080s12.080 5.408 12.080 12.080z"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.8" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" d="M17.86 7.86l-10 10"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.8" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" d="M17.84 17.84l-9.96-9.96"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: What generator are you talking about?

Comment: Hi there - IcoMoon and Fontastic

Comment: What answer do you expect? Both are webservices that have decided to rewrite your sources. It's a design decision, they do not supply configuration options,, by using their services you agree to their terms.

Comment: I was hoping to better understand why they did converted to paths and learn more about my SVG code

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are rewritten as paths, presentation attributes have been moved from the `<svg>` element to the contained `<paths>`s. An `id` attribute has been removed. If the web services you are using have reasons for doing that, they do not publicly share them (or at least I haven't found doc on that). Giving opinions on the why must remain outside the scope of this answer.

The attribute `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` you used is not part of the SVG 1.1 specification, but only SVG 1.2 Tiny and the SVG 2 draft. Internet Explorer does not support this attribute, so removing it improves browser compatibility.

Adding `stroke-miterlimit="4"` is objectivly useless, as that is the default value.

There is a library [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) that could rewrite the code in the way you see it (almost, excluding the default value issue), but I cannot tell for sure if the services are using that.